# Nested Structure Usage in C

Tags: c, nested, structure, typedef

From the below given snippet.

```
            typedef struct {
                int Code;
                int ParentCode;
            }TypeStudentConfidential;

            typedef struct {
                int age;
                int RollNo;
                int Rank;
                char Name[10];
            }TypeStudent;

            typedef struct {
                char class_name[20];
                //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX //How could I declare the TypeClass element here?
            }TypeClass;

            int main()
            {

               const TypeStudent  Stu_Details[] = {
                 { 3,   1,  18, "Mahesh"},
                 { 3,   1,   7,  "Kumar"}
               };

               const TypeStudentConfidential Conf_Details[] = {
                 { 761, 814},
                 { 124, 562}
               };

               const TypeClass Class_Details[]= {
                 { "Class 10",     Stu_Details},  //struct TypeStudent data
                 { "Class 8",     Conf_Details}   //struct TypeStudentConfidential data
               };

               return 0;
            }
```

Questions:

1) How to define the ***XXXXXX*** marked typedef struct element

2) How to access the ***XXXXXX*** marked element from ***Class_Details***

Comment: We are no review or tutoring service. Please read [ask].

Comment: TypeStudent and TypeStudentConfidential are different structures. You should not store one's address in a pointer of another type.

Comment: `Now I'm stuck....` is a pretty weak problem-statement. Please described clearly the problem you have, e.g. compile error or runtime error or.... BTW: Storing `TypeStudentConfidential` in something that expects `TypeStudent` will not work. Maybe you need a `union`

Comment: I have updated the snippet.

Comment: I believe your snippet is indented incorrectly... Please fix it? Additionally, this is not a *minimal working example*; please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct TypeClass {
    char class_name[20];
    struct TypeStudent* type;
} TypeClass;
```

and to access

```
Typeclass a = {"classA", NULL};
Typeclass b = {"classB", NULL};
a.type = &b;
printf("%s\n", a.type->class_name); //prints b's classname
```

Now if you want XXXXXXXXXX to be either a TypeStudent OR TypeStudentConfidential (as your code snippit seems to suggest) you'll probably need to use a `union`, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct TypeClass{
        char class_name[20];
        union type {
                struct TypeStudent* students;
                struct TypeStudentConfidential* studentConfs;
        } type;
} TypeClass;

typedef struct TypeStudent {
        int age;
        int RollNo;
        int Rank;
        char Name[10];
} TypeStudent;

typedef struct TypeStudentConfidential {
        int Code;
        int ParentCode;
} TypeStudentConfidential;

int main() {
        //TypeClass a[2] = {{"C0", {NULL}}, {"C1", {NULL}}};

        TypeStudent studs[2]  = {{10, 10, 10, "Joe"}, {5, 5, 5, "Bob"}};
        TypeStudentConfidential confs[2]  = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

        TypeClass a[2] = {{"C0", {.students = studs}}, {"C1", {.studentConfs = confs}}};

        //a[0].type.students = studs;
        //a[1].type.studentConfs = confs;

        printf("%s, %s\n", a[0].type.students->Name, (a[0].type.students + 1)->Name);
        printf("%i, %i\n", a[1].type.studentConfs->Code, (a[1].type.studentConfs + 1)->Code);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: thankyou. this solves the question from my perspective. 

I am using the example with an edit, i.e I have removed **.students =** and **.studentConfs =**

Comment: while using something similar using ARM Windows GCC C Compiler, i got an error response saying w.r.t this example: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type for Name in students of type TypeStudent